# Select last Item in long List Selector

Tags: windows-phone-8

![![>I want to add this Tile in the end of the Long list selector Item so I can navigate to new Add >page (I should pass the Table Id as a parameter so I can insert my order in the selected Table ). >the selected change work only when my Tile is a Long List Selector Item. ??

> Thanks][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPmw9.png)

Comment: What is your attempt so far? I do not know to help, but the guys who do want to see some effort from your part first. :)

Comment: what exactly you want to do?

Comment: I want to add this Tile in the end of the Long list selector Item so I can navigate to new Add >page (I should pass the Table Id as a parameter so I can insert my order in the selected Table ). >the selected change work only when my Tile is a Long List Selector Item. ??(i have joined a Picture describing what i want to do exactly,hope its clear for you)

Answer (score 1):

You can set the last item as the selected one when you initialize the ItemsSource property of the long list selector:

```
    LongListSelector.ItemsSource = myList;
    LongListSelector.SelectedItem = myList.Last();
    LongListSelector.ScrollTo(myList.Last()); //if you want to scroll to that element as well
```

Hope this example will help you.

Comment: I want to add this Tile in the end of the Long list selector Item so I can navigate to new Add >page (I should pass the Table Id as a parameter so I can insert my order in the selected Table ). >the selected change work only when my Tile is a Long List Selector Item. ??(i have joined a Picture in my edited question describing what i want to do exactly,hope its clear for you)

Comment: LongListSelector.ItemsSource = myList;
    LongListSelector.SelectedItem = myList.Last(); is not working :( i want to show selected value on page load, i tried your approach but didn't work, any other solutions ?